# Removing WordPress Files from a server

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a server with hundreds of websites they all have the WordPress files however we only need the important files for example, wp-config, theme, plugins.

I'm looking to run something to clear all WordPress files.

What's my best solution?

Comment: True, I don't know what's relevant here to be honest.

Comment: You should probably use the wordpress and bash tags. Also, providing information about the directory structure would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to eliminate double files. Stick one wp setup in a folder somewhere and symlink the rest per site.

That way every site gets everything but the specific files such as wo-config.php and /wp-content/ and such from your one copy.